# React DOM not (properly) updating after state change

Tags: reactjs

The behavior on this one has me perplexed.  Created a list by clicking "Add Button" several times.  Deleting an item from the list (by clicking the "Delete" next to the item) properly removes the item from the list (and updates the State) but the display shows the LAST item is removed and the item you selected to delete remains.  Am I not properly updating the state:

```
import { useState } from "react"

export const App = () => {
    const [records, setRecords] = useState({ data: [], errState: false })

    const addRecord = () => {
        let newList = [...records.data]
        newList.push(`This Will Be Record ${newList.length}`)
        console.log(newList)
        setRecords(ps => ({ ...ps, data: newList }))
    }

    const delRecord = ({ target }) => {
        const id = parseInt(target.getAttribute("data-row"))
        let newList = [...records.data]
        newList.splice(id, 1)
        setRecords(ps => ({ ...ps, data: newList }))
    }

    const buildRows = () => {
        return records.data.map((r, rndx) => {
            return (
                <div style={{ display: "flex",marginBottom:"10px" }}>
                    <div style={{ flex: 1, paddingRight: "20px" }}><input id={`test-${rndx}`}/></div>
                    <div style={{ width: "50px" }}><button onClick={delRecord} data-row={rndx}>Delete</button></div>
                </div>

            )
        })
    }

    return (
        <div style={{ width: "800px", margin: "0 auto", textAlign: "center" }}>
            {buildRows()}
            <button onClick={addRecord}>Add Record</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/zen-breeze-mlcn87?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.js%3A1%2C1-55%2C1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider having a unique id for each item that is not derived from its array index. Use this id value as the [`key` prop](https://react.dev/learn/rendering-lists#keeping-list-items-in-order-with-key) when rendering the items to ensure React deletes the appropriate element from the DOM:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const App = () => {
  const [records, setRecords] = useState({ data: [], errState: false });

  const addRecord = () => {
    let newList = [...records.data];
    newList.push({
      value: `This Will Be Record ${newList.length}`,
      id: Date.now(),
    });
    console.log(newList);
    setRecords((ps) => ({ ...ps, data: newList }));
  };

  const delRecord = ({ target }) => {
    const id = parseInt(target.getAttribute('data-row'));
    let newList = records.data.filter((item) => item.id !== id);
    setRecords((ps) => ({ ...ps, data: newList }));
  };

  const buildRows = () => {
    return records.data.map((r) => {
      return (
        <div style={{ display: 'flex', marginBottom: '10px' }} key={r.id}>
          <div style={{ flex: 1, paddingRight: '20px' }}>
            <input id={`test-${r.id}`} />
          </div>
          <div style={{ width: '50px' }}>
            <button onClick={delRecord} data-row={r.id}>
              Delete
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    });
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ width: '800px', margin: '0 auto', textAlign: 'center' }}>
      {buildRows()}
      <button onClick={addRecord}>Add Record</button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<App />);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: First, thanks for pointing out the missing key prop, but your suggestion un-broke the code.  Thanks for you response @Wongjs